# Error running pod install. Error launching application on iPhone 8

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods

After running my app I get this error:
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 8.

I've tried already:
Uncommenting the line

#platformform: iOS, 9.0

and

1. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
2. arch -x86_64 pod install

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete pods folder from your project/ios
2. Delete .symlinks from project/ios
3. Delete podfile.lock
4. Run arch -x86_64 pod install
5. Then try flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Please access your Podfile, and you will notice that the first few lines contain the following information.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}
```

Scroll down and comment out these three lines.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 # target 'RunnerTests' do
 #   inherit! :search_paths
 # end
```